# using awk -F to split a text file in tcsh

Tags: split, terminal, tcsh

Been a while since I've tried tcsh but can't tell what I'm doing wrong here. I have a text file: 'patient1_001';'patient2_001';'patient3_001'...

I'm trying to use terminal to split by ";" and give a line by line readout:

```
patient1_001
patient2_001
patient3_001
```

tried this:

```
cat patientfile.txt | awk -F "[;]" '{printf "%s\n",$1}'
```

but I'm just getting the first output (patient1_001). I tried working in a for loop but with no luck:

```
cat patientfile.txt | awk -F "[;]" '{for(i=1;i=10;i++){printf "%s\n",$i}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This hasn't anything in particular to do with tcsh.  The same behavior would be seen in any other shell.  The awk command you are using splits each line into fields using the the semicolon as a delimiter, and then prints (just) the first field.  If effectively you just want to convert semicolons into newlines then I suggest a simple sed program instead:

```
cat patientfile.txt | sed 's/;/\n/g'
```

Comment: this is giving me 'patient1_001'n'patient2_002'...  could the ' marks in the text file be throwing things off?

Comment: Hmm.  No, @user3470496, single or double quotation marks in the data should not have any special significance.  But while we're on that, did you want to remove them?  You say you want to split by ";", and that's all it appears your `awk` command is trying to do, but your example output does not preserve the quotation marks.

Comment: Anyway, the problem appears to be that the single-quotes in the command are not successfully quoting the backslash within.  They should, and I am not aware of any setting or option that would change that.  Are you in fact running the command, exactly as written, from the command line?  Copy and paste it if necessary.